# how to convert integer variable having values greater than the integer size to string in talend

Tags: talend

upon running my job in talend, it is throwing an
tfileinputdelimited_1 For input string "xxxxxxx" error.
the job is dumping the flat file data via tfileinputdelimited to toracleoutput.
upon checking the table column i found out that one of the column that is defined as an integer contains values like "8000004016" which is above the integer size.

also i tried some cast options and codes in talend but without success.
it keeps poping cannot convert integer to string.

can anyone help me out in explaining this error and guide me with the steps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Integer. Switch to Long or BigDecimal, depending on your requirements.